# Intellij as a PostgreSQL editor

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, pgadmin

I use an IDEA Intellij as a SQL editor (great SQL support) but I can not find a way how to display a window called: "SQL pane" in pgAdmin:

[image]

It is important to me, to know how table was created. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the database / table create statements via context menu on a database / table - > "Copy DDL" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).